# Laravel Nova display user-friendly resource name

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Let's say that I have a resource called "Resource_test". When I'm displaying that resource in Nova, that resource name (or "label") displays the name as-is which obviously isn't very user-friendly.

Is it possible to rename the "label" to "Resource Test" (without the underscore for example)?

It seems like they set the name in the file `src\Nova.php` on the static function `resourceInformation` but even though I change the name there, it doesn't seem to change the name on the site itself...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can override the static label method within the resource class like this:

```
public static function label() {
    return 'Your own label';
}
```

You'll find your resource classes in the `app/Nova` directory. Do not confuse these classes with the identically-named models! Adding the `label` method to the model will not work.

You can take a look at the `Nova\src\Resource.php` class to view all the options.

Comment: You're an angel! It worked! Can't believe I didn't find that, Thank you! :D

Comment: Amazing! Thanks

Comment: How do you reference the resource? So if I want $resource->total to be the title.

Comment: public function __construct($resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

At the constructor, $this->resource is set. Think you can access $this->resource->total ?

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I have overridden the methods label and singularLabel to return my custom name. Is there anything I need to restart for something after doing this ?

Comment: Just in case if you need to provide singular label name for a certain language, override `singularLabel()` static method.